# Set field to 1, but if it's already 1 set it to NULL

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, case

I want to update a row in the table with a 1, but if it's already 1 set it to `NULL`, how do I most efficiently check if the row is already 1?

```
<?php
session_start();
$ai = $_POST['ai'];
$set = NULL or 1 depending on row fav is NULL or 1 
include ("connect.php");
$sql = $con->prepare('UPDATE list SET fav = ? WHERE id=?');
$sql->bind_param("si",$set, $ai);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
?>
```

Comment: can i check that in the sql query?

Comment: yes that is what im trying to do

Comment: dont know what its called

Comment: both answer works great, thanks alot for the help, I dont know which one is most efficient but I'l take the one with the least amount of characters:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want a flip switch between 1 and NULL.

```
UPDATE list SET fav = IF(fav IS NULL, 1, NULL) WHERE id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
update list
set fav = (case when fav = 1 then null else 1 end)
where id = ?
```

If `fav` is `1`, this sets it to `null`, else it is set to `1`.

This query accepts a single parameter, that is the `id` of the row that you want to `update`.